# How do I make an automake rule in an .mk file that deletes a directory upon cleaning?

Tags: automake, cxxtest

I would like to delete a another directory when I run make clean, but I can't figure out how to code it up in the rules.

I have tried

```
clean-local:
  -rm -f del.dir
```

but that didn't work.

I also tried

```
CLEANFILES = del.dir
```

but that also didn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated,

Comment: "but that didn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful. Can you edit your post to include error messages or any other output from `make`?

Answer (score 1):

`clean-local` should work, but the command to erase a directory is `rm -rf dir`, not `rm -f dir`.